# Tomcat 8 connectionTimeout issu

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, connection-timeout

For some network issues, I have tried to set an infinite connectionTimeout for my connector.So, I set **connectionTimeout="-1"**

But When I run my web application, I get a strange exception:my http filter is no longer getting http request parameters.
When I remove connectionTimeout, every think works fine.

Any idea about this behaviour?
Thanks

Comment: Post your exceptions and any other relevant information you have.

Comment: Hi Alex,
I'm not getting any exception,just I'm no longer getting my request parameters using (request.getParameter("paramname"))

Comment: You said:  "But When I run my web application, I get a strange exception", have you made sure that the XML for the config is still valid after your change?  Did you check catalina.out for any errors?

Comment: Sorry , I mean "strange behaviour".
I didn't find any exception in catalina.out file :(

The server.xml config file is valid, if I modify **-1** by any positive value,I get the expected bahaviour

Comment: I have not had any issues with this, I tested it with , can you post your server.xml at least, it's hard trying to help you when you are not providing any unseful information other than it's not working for me.  Post any relevant startup from localhost log and catalina log; so people know how to help you.

Comment: I just tested:  setting Connector attribute connectionTimeout="-1" and it worked, did you remove the old attribute there with "20000" value?